# Economic Lagrange problem, 2 constraints and 2 inequalities

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, economics

I need to solve this problem, it's been 12 years since I graduated so I really don't remember much :) hopefully some1 can help

There is a factory which have 2 suppliers where X and Y represent the amount paid to each supplier
The factory has a profit function as such
$$\begin{align*}F(X,Y) &= 0.000002X^2Y + 0.000008X^2 + 180,000\\
S.T.\\
X + Y &\leq 100000\\
X &\geq 20000\end{align*}$$

Edit:
So I did the Following (L will mark lambda)

$$0.000002X^2Y + 0.000008X^2 + 180,000 + \lambda_1(100000 - x - y) + \lambda_2(-20000 + X) = 0$$
I did all the math for partial derivatives and I still can't get the right answer

I also used solver and wolfram alpha to solve it, and both gave the correct answer which I didn't manage to obtain

Can some one help me with the solution, inc all the step?

Edit, I think I got it now, will appreciate remarks:

first I decided to change the lagrange, removing the second constraint
$$\begin{align*}
0.000002X^2Y + 0.000008X^2 + 180,000 + \lambda_1(100000 - x - y) = 0\end{align*}$$

next I solve the derivate

$$\frac{\delta(X,Y)}{\delta(X)} =0.000004XY + 0.000016X - \lambda_1 = 0$$

$$\frac{\delta(X,Y)}{\delta(Y)} = 0.000002X^2 - \lambda_1 = 0$$

$$\frac{\delta(X,Y)}{\delta(\lambda_1)} = 100000 - X - Y = 0$$

next I solved those 3 equations and got that X is 66666.669 and Y is 33333.34

and those also apply to the second constraint so all is ok, I just don't understand why Ignoring the second constraint in lagrage allowed me to solve it so easily

keep in mind I graduated 12 years ago, and I didn't touch this stuff since then :)
thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. I made an attempt to help with typesetting. Please let me know if I got something wrong.

Comment: @mathreadler thanks :) I didn't know how to do it myself :)

Comment: There is a guide somewhere on the site which can be good to check out but it seems you are already up to speed :)

Comment: @Tnimni Any further questions?

Comment: @callculus no, thank you

Comment: @Tnimni You´re welcome. Should I undelete my answer?

Comment: @callculus please undelete if you wish